# Mongodb aggregation array partition and count

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb aggregation problem that I haven't managed to solve.  So far in my aggregation I have a filter, a *$project* and an *$accumulator* using a javascript function that has managed to reduce the data I have to an array of arrays like this: **[[A, B], [A, C], [A,B, [C, D], ...]**. These values **A**, **B** etc... are objects with 4 or 5 keys & values that represent people, and the **[A, B]** pairs representation relationships between people. This list is very long and in some - not even very large - queries, the mongodb limit of 16MB for generating BSON to return is hit.

I can use *$setIntersection* to reduce the list's size so it works but what I really want to be able to do is to reduce the list to the unique values contained in it along with a count for each unique value. This could be represented in several ways but, to illustrate it, I might want this structure: **[[[A, B], 2], [[A, C], 1], [[C, D], 1]], ...]**.

Does anyone here have any suggestions on how I might do this? I've tried several things but nothing has worked yet. If the javascript in my mongo (4.4.1) implemented object hashes and sets, then I could easily do it in my accumulator; but it doesn't. I suppose I could write my own implementations of hash/set but that seems like overkill. I haven't managed to find a mechanism using aggregation pipeline operators. I think that would be the best thing to do but I'm not sure...

As requested by here is some more details about the data. The data returned by the filter stage is like this (obviously very summarised, Bob, Mark etc.. are objects):

```
[
  {
    …
    users: [
      Bob,
      Mary.
      Mark
    ] 
    …
  },
  {
    …
    users: [
      Andrew,
      Mary,
      Mark
    ] 
    …
  }.
  {
    …
    users: [
      Bob,
      Mark
    ] 
    …
  }
]
```

The first stage of processing (which I've done in an **$Accumulator**) is, for each record, to get all the pairs of user A -> user B relationships, as shown here (one line per record):

```
[
  [Bob, Mary], [Bob, Mark], [Mary, Bob], [Mary, Mark], [Mark, Bob], [Mark, Mary],
  [Andrew, Mary], [Andrew, Mark], [Mary, Andrew], [Mary, Mark], [Mark, Andrew], [Mark, Mary],
  [Bob, Mark], [Mark, Bob]
]
```

But this list gets very long. I want to summarise by finding the unique pairs and counting them, to get something like this. OK, I've written this as arrays but it could take any other form that has the same meaning:

```
[
  [[Bob, Mary], 1],
  [[Bob, Mark], 2],
  [[Mary, Bob], 1],
  [[Mary, Mark], 2],
  [[Mark, Bob], 2],
  [[Mark, Mary], 2],
  [[Andrew, Mary], 1],
  [[Andrew, Mark], 1],
  [[Mary, Andrew], 1],
  [[Mark, Andrew], 1],
]
```

I hope this clarifies things. Of course there could be a completely different approach to the way I'm doing it. I'm open to whatever would work best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$setUnion` to get unique elements from that array
- `$map` to iterate loop of above unique elements
- `$filter` to iterate loop of array and get matching elements
- `$size` to get above filtered result count

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      field: {
        $map: {
          input: { $setUnion: "$field" },
          in: [
            "$$this",
            {
              $size: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$field",
                  as: "a",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$this", "$$a"] }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kY8eo0Z2XZb)